# Streaming google drive video in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, video-streaming

I have a google drive video and I want to stream it with react native. I do not want to download it before and then enable the player. I want a stream it in live directly.

I use this library: [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video)

I've try this:

```
<Video source={{
    uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/ID?alt=media",
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer STUFF',
    }
}} />
```

But I've got this error

NSURLErrorDomain error -1002 means NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL